# Linking up my database values

Tags: php, sql

I've successfully been able to display array values on my PHP page like this:

```
Date Time Created:

2014-09-15 07:20:02

2014-09-15 07:20:52

2014-09-15 07:29:19

2014-09-15 22:54:39

2014-09-15 23:02:46
```

Using the following PHP:

```
<?php
echo "<p> Date Time Created: </p>";
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT datetimecreated FROM example_DB");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
foreach($row as &$value) {
echo "$value<br />\n";
echo "<br />\n";
}
}
?>
```

My next step is to link each data value (in this case datetimecreated) to its own PHP page. 
Ideally, I'd like to create a template PHP and then SELECT and echo the details of the clicked value to the template, rather than create a new PHP page for each value.

How can I determine which value the user has clicked?
Is it possible to do this with the code I've used so far?

Comment: change the echo part in the foreach loop. "<a href='yourfilename?name='.$value.'>.$value. </a>"; its a hint

Comment: Got the hint! Going to have to go back a few pages and change some more code but this should work. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome make sure you dont have any syntax error. as i have  in my comment. Thanks

Comment: in the last comment i did have syntax error. so i deleted it. this one is with syntax error. try this echo echo "<a href='yourfilename.php?link=$home'>".$home."</a>"; Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for

This is what you code should look like

```
<?php
    echo "<p> Date Time Created: </p>";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT datetimecreated FROM example_DB");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    foreach($row as &$value) {
    echo "<a href='yourfilename.php?name='".$value."'>".$value."</a><br />";
    echo "<br />";
    }
    }
?>
```

Below is the code what you will need to add to the filename you used instead of "yourfilename.php" what is in the link you created. The below code needs to be at the top so nothing is loaded before it because no point trying to do queries when you have nothing to do them with.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["name"])){
        $n = preg_replace('#[^0-9 :-]#i', '', $_GET['name']);
    } else {
        exit(header("location: index.php?msg=nonameset")); }
?>
```

When you have got the name in a variable you can use it do query the database to get more linked info.

This comment added upon request:

I am using preg replace to take out any unwanted characters what helps quite a bit in security and because you will be doing a database query you need to take any unwanted characters out otherwise you might regret it.

Can I also add that I am quite new to PHP also so do not hesitate to correct me. Thanks

Comment: its ok dude. explain to him why you are using preg_replace as i am sure he dont know. Thanks

Comment: I have added a quick explanation

Comment: Post a full solution. so if he cant do it. and come back here. he can do it with you solution. an i dont know why you are using exit. header he might not have those file and variable. just echo out some message like echo 'not allowed' Thanks

Comment: I do not have time to post a full solution atm. I will post a full solution when I have managed to finish the work i have planned for today. Sorry but I need to get this done.

Comment: dont worry if you post the full solution. and it does work i will upvote your answer. take your time

Comment: I am not sure if he is bothered anymore anyway

Comment: yah but you posted the answer quick so i am giving you a upvote. some people are like that they got the solution then they run away